# What is an appropriate way to tell a project manager their timeline is unrealistic?

Tags: professionalism, project-management, time-management

I have a few project managers that I answer to, and therefore, every now and then I'll have to work out prioritizing my work, thus, delaying the work handed to me by other project managers. The problem is they usually say something like "Have this to me by Friday" when it's unrealistic to even have it done within the next two weeks regardless of whether or not I have other projects to work on or not.

I don't want to start telling them I cannot do their projects, however, because that would ultimately lead to someone else getting the work and having me look like I don't care about the job. I just need a professional way to give my project managers a realistic outlook of their time frame.

Comment: @DavidK thanks. Couldn't think of the word deadline. Should I delete my question or close?

Comment: Additionally to protesting deadlines, you also need to manage your matrix managers.

Comment: @JakenHerman I'm actually not sure on that one. I would lean towards deletion, but you might stick around a bit and see if a mod has a different opinion.

Comment: I think this is different than the duplicate that is just estimate.  This is also about prioritization.  If you can do a last minute request in 1 week it is not fair to the other projects in the queue that all got pushed back one week.  Put a list of project on the white board and line under the X you are currently working on.  Put the project at the bottom of the list and tell them they need to get approval from the project managers of the X active to have their projects put on hold.